# iframe in IE going blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I have a aspx page containing an iframe which shows a pdf ( i have ashx handler to display pdf in iframe), I also have a download button which onclick stream's a different pdf to the browser as an attachment. 
download to browser code: (this is in ashx handler)

```
    byte[] bytes =  // get byte array from table
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    // [optional]
    Response.AddHeader(
           "Content-Disposition",
           string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", attachmentName)
     );
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Response.End();
```

This code works fine however after sending this response to the browser my iframe goes blank and I have to refresh the page in order to see it again. I tried most of the solutions

1. http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies
2. http://forums.asp.net/p/1036628/1433536.aspx

but none of them is working. iframe behaves fine in chrome & FF.
Note: if i do downloading stuff using asp:hyperlink to my ashx and setting target="_blank" it works fine in IE but i need some server side processing to do therefore i cant use this method.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? What versions have you tried?

Comment: I use IE9 n I have tried IE 7,8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Chrome and FF leave the page there, this does actually make sense.

You are posting back to the server, then clearing your whole output, placing a file in the stream and sending that. Technically I would say IE is right in blanking out the page.

This is assuming your download button is in the iframe?

The solution I would try is putting that download link in another iFrame or have another page that downloads it and when you press a link it opens the new page which just outputs a file. So the window flashes up but then it disappears and a save dialog button appears. However popup blockers might try to stop this.

Comment: download button is not in the iframe, button is on the aspx page. Download button calls a ashx handler which puts response to the browser. I cant have a link instead of a button because I have to do some server side processing (to determine which pdf file has to be sent to client) and pass query string params to handler to get the correct pdf.

Comment: So why not put the button in an iframe as I suggested?

Comment: thanks for answering, now I am using another window for download only. putting a button in an iframe makes it complex for the user because of scrolling..